# excel, sheet1 row A value equals sheet2 row A

Tags: worksheet-function

entire sheet1 row A value equals sheet2 row A?  so, whatever data i enter in sheet1 row A will transfers to sheet2 row A automatically...  also, how do enter a function for an entire row?

thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a macro to do the job... or you could say (in sheet2, cell A1 ) `=Sheet1!A1`

and drag the formula.. this ensures that the changes in sheet1 are shown on sheet2.